# Azure VM change IP address to static via CLI

Tags: azure, static, command-line-interface

I am taking a course and stuck for almost a week. I created a VM and now it wants me to change the IP config method to static. The exact words are.

"You have created a ubuntu virtual machine in the second step, in which check the public IP (publicIpAllocationMethod) address and change it to Static by executing the azure CLI commands."

I created the VM with below command.
*az vm create -n MyVm1 -g groupname --admin-username "n1234" --admin-password "nk123@9090" --location westUS --image UbuntuLTS*

Got the VM NIC with below command.
*nic_id=$(az vm show -g gropname -n MyVm1 -d --query networkProfile.networkInterfaces[0].id)
az network nic show --ids MyVm1VMNic*

I have the IP of the VM but not sure how to change it to static.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/nic/ip-config?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-nic-ip-config-update

With your example, you would run the following:

```
nic_id=$(az vm show -g gropname -n MyVm1 -d --query 

networkProfile.networkInterfaces[0].id --output tsv)
nicName=$(az network nic show --ids $nic_id --query name --output tsv)
ipconfig=$(az network nic show --ids $nic_id --query ipConfigurations[0].name
--output tsv)
az network nic ip-config update -g gropname --nic-name $nicName -n $ipconfig --private-ip-address <static ip address>
```

By setting the private IP, the IP configuration will be updated to static. The above code relies on the VM having a single NIC, which is assumed based on your example.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I got it yesterday with the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved by using the below command.

*az network public-ip update -g GROUPNAME -n MyVm1PublicIP --allocation-method Static*